# Submit button outside of form component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

my Submit button is outside of the form and different component. The problem is I have no idea how to make it working. This my example code and [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/best-example-of-passing-data-through-an-object-using-a-s-f4e5sm) demo

**Component One(HTML)**

```
<div class="formContainer">
  <div class="name">
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Name"
           name="name"
           [(ngModel)]="firstName">
  </div>

  <div class="email">
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Email"
           name="email"
           [(ngModel)]="email">
  </div>
  <div class="genderContainer">
    <div class="male" (click)="male()" [ngStyle]="{'backgroundColor': btnClickedMale ? '#0543a5': '#dddddd'}">M</div>
    <div class="female" (click)="female()" [ngStyle]="{'backgroundColor': btnClickedFemale ? '#0543a5': '#dddddd'}">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Component Two(HTML)**

```
<div class="btnContainer">
    <button (click)="submitBtn()">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why would you need a submit button outside? It is possible but it will become a dirty solution.

Comment: Because I want to reusable submit button

Comment: Re-use the form. Put the button inside and on submit, just pass the event with all the details to the parent component for submit button logic. This will ensure that the form is re-used and all validations and stuff are inside form. However, if you still need to go with that logic; here is the updated stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/best-example-of-passing-data-through-an-object-using-a-s-qnikat

Comment: My lecture want me to use that logic..Thank you so much brother..It working!!!...Can you add it in answer? so that  I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend putting the button inside and on submit, just pass the event with all the details to the parent component for submit button logic. This will ensure that the form is re-used and all validations and stuff are inside form.

However, if you still need to go with that logic; here is the updated stackblitz demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/best-example-of-passing-data-through-an-object-using-a-s-qnikat

Comment: if you wouldn’t mind.. Can I ask you one more question... when I click submit button...and pass data in `submitBtn() {}` in component one?

Comment: Yes you can call it using the ViewChild created like `this.app1.submitBtn();`. I have updated the stackblitz demo in case you need a working copy.